# C++ STL: Using transform to copy keys of one map into a dissimilar map, filling in default values?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to convert something like this:

```
const map<string, string> digits = {{"zero", "0"},{"one", "1"},{"two", "2"},{"three", "3"},{"four", "4"},{"five", "5"},{"six", "6"},{"seven", "7"},{"eight", "8"},{"nine", "9"}};
```

Into this:

```
map<string, uint> out = {{"zero", 0},{"one", 0},{"two", 0},{"three", 0},{"four", 0},{"five", 0},{"six", 0},{"seven", 0},{"eight", 0},{"nine", 0}};
```

In a short way using STL algorithms.

I've tried many things, but right now I'm at:

```
map<string, uint> counting;
transform(begin(digits), end(digits), inserter(counting, end(counting)), [](auto & p) {
    return {p.first, 0};
});
```

and am scratching my head as to how I do this... Is there a way to use the transform algorithm on dissimilar iterators?

Answer (score 1):

You must return a `std::map<std::string, uint>::value_type`, which is a `std::pair<std::string, uint>`.

```
std::transform(std::begin(digits), std::end(digits), std::inserter(counting, std::end(counting)), [](auto & p) {
    return std::pair{p.first, 0}; // deduced template arguments
});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d6KdMnhqc)

You can also use `std::for_each` with a capturing lambda instead:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(digits), std::end(digits), [&counting](auto & p) {
    counting.emplace(p.first, 0);
});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1dPfnv4P4)

Though this isn't shorter than a for loop:

```
for (auto const& e : digits) {
    counting.emplace(e.first, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `std::map` iterators are [bidirectional iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) while `std::insert_iterator` (created by `std::inserter`) is an [output iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator) (as required by [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)), and the two operator types are not compatible.

Reason being that `std::map` is *ordered* and you can't insert values at arbitrary positions.

So you can't use `std::transform` to copy into a map.

The simplest workaround is a plain [range `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to add elements to the destination map. Or `std::for_each` as shown in [Nelfeal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74380893/440558).

Comment: I believe we were both wrong. See my edit.

Comment: That page on bidirectional iterators says "A mutable LegacyBidirectionalIterator is a LegacyBidirectionalIterator that additionally satisfies the LegacyOutputIterator requirements".